# Create a Full-Width page in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

How do I get the full width? On the right side there was a sidebar. I removed it. There is no option "Full-Width" on the drop down menu under Template option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the theme is hardcoded to use 70% of the width in the style.css.  You can add this custom CSS to your style.css file in your child theme folder to make it 100% width.

```
#primary {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The breakpoint for mobile devices already seems to be 100% width but there's no margin on the container so the content is flush against the screen edge which looks weird.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1023px) {
  #primary {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    padding: 0px;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
  }
}
```